# Physical meaning of this boundary value differential equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, calculus

(I originally posted this on math stack exchange but was advised to post it here)

I am considering the following boundary value problem:
$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ a(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(u(x)) \right] + c(x)u(x) = f(x),$$
 where $x \in [0,1]$ and $u(0) = u(1) = 0.$

I searched through the boyce and diprima differential equations book but did not find any physical interpretation to the differential equation above with the given boundary conditions. From what I've seen, the equation above arises as a result of solving PDEs. I'm looking for a physical interpretation for the diff eq itself.

More specifically, it'd be great if someone can point me to a reference which specifies what $a(x),c(x),f(x),u(x)$ can mean. I already have an idea of how my $a(x)$ will be represented. I intend to play around with $c(x),f(x)$ to obtain interesting looking solutions $u(x)$. However, I don't want to just blindly play around with $c(x),f(x)$ not knowing what they mean.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What Real World problem does the DE represent? First of all, what is the actual DE?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gert. That was actually my question. I have the differential equation but I'd like to know where it arises in a physical setting.

Comment: It seems to be a Sturm–Liouville equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory. But many physical problems require that kind of DE. E.g. if I'm not mistake, the Schrodinger (time independent) equation is a SL type DE.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2541430/11127

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: This is the Sturm-Liouville equation. It arises most commonly as related to boundary value problems / eigenvalue problems in PDEs. When you use separation of variables in PDEs (heat equation, wave equation), and versions of them like the Schrodinger equation for example, you impose boundary conditions, which lead to the spatial solutions being orthogonal eigenfunctions which satisfy the ODE you have listed above. The specific eigenvalues you have cited here, $u(0) = u(1) = 0$, correspond to Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the type of equation you mentioned in lectures I heard on "Methods on the solutions of ordinary & partial differential equations". As example for its usefulness the "heat equation in thermodynamical equilibrium" was cited. In thermodynamical equilibrium the partial time-derivative of temperature "field" is zero, whereas an (in time) constant heat source $f(x)$ is assumed to be non-zero. The solution of this (boundary) problem is the temperature distribution $u(x)$. The coefficient $a(x)$ corresponds to an anisotropic diffusion coefficient (The coefficient $c$ is zero in this example, I regret). If you consult wikipedia on "heat equation" you will get good overview on most of the details of this type of problem. 
Actually, in the meantime it is considered more like an engineering problem which might explain why you did not find much information on it in physics literature. (Actually such problems of this type also exist in elasticity theory.)

Actually it is a typically engineering problem where for instance some material part of a mechanical device (defined by an area $\Omega$) is exposed to a constant heat source and the question is if in the considered area $\Omega$ a certain (unacceptable) temperature limit is exceeded. The approach is often by the use of finite elements FE(as presented in the lecture I heard). Plenty commercial software for doing this job already exits.
Therefore this problem type, I would say, already left the field physicists are really interested in.

But the heat equation only differs from the Schroedinger equation by an imaginary $i$ in the time-dependent part, this $i$ is no longer in the time-independent Schroedinger equation, therefore  the time-independent Schroedinger equation (SE) also has the form of the equation you cite. However, very often the functions $c(x)$ in the SE have a singular point, which actually requires different solutions techniques as in the first example I mentioned.

Of course I only mentioned one respectively two examples, actually there are plenty of other examples of the use of this equation. However, as already mentioned for the SE, the properties of the different functions $a$, $b$, $u$ and $f$ applied in the mathematical lectures often are not fulfilled in equations of this type in physics, so other techniques were used by physicists to solve such equations. Those are often so different that you will hardly recognize them compared to those typically shown in mathematical lectures (e.g. the one I heard).

Answer (score 0):

In a particular case in which c(x) = V(x)/a(x) and f(x)=0, this is a typical wave equation with potential V(x).

u(x) may very well represent the wave function. This problem were solved firstly in quantum mechanics as a scattering problem given different potentials V(x).

There are off course a bunch of other eminent problems related to it, as an example, the field propagation problem around black holes and stars in general relativity. The equation seems to describe very well multiple fields (with different spins), that just differ in the potential V(x).

It's useful, in many different applications such as the study of 'plane waves' in known geometries. It is still possible to conjecture relations of this field propagation and thermodynamics of the geometry...

Comment: That is one example but w/o knowing $a(x)$, $c(x)$ and $f(x)$ we're just guessing what physical reality this represents.

Comment: Not sure about what do you mean by 'physical reality'. When f(x)=0, a(x)*c(x) = V(x), you cal stipulate a particular physical reality of a wave equation that can be solved in multiple contexts depending on the potential.

This means, for example, when you throw something at a black hole, it can be governed by this equation.

You can also think the very basics, in the 2nd newtonian law: F=ma. Without knowing what kind of force, we cannot guess what system this equation represents.(It may works for every newtonian system as the wave equation for every wave with a V(x)).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rodrigo. Do you happen to have references on this? Or for example, what can I type on google to search for this? If I type wave equation, I end up with the time dependent problem.

Comment: Sure have, user1237300:

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/16/12/201/meta

Take a look in equation (47/48) in the old "r" coordinate (the transformation is in equation 46) . This is the equation for gravitational perturbation in a Schwarzschild black hole.

Also in https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.12942%2Flrr-1999-2.pdf

equation 5 and 21.

You have to take the time derivative as "-iw" to obtain a similar equation as the one you are working with. "w" here is an imaginary frequency called "quasi-normal mode".

Comment: If you type quasi-normal mode, you may encounter more than 1000 papers on the subject...

The basic equation is similar to the one you quote.

Comment: As for quantum mechanics take a look in any common textbook the different potentials (barrier potential for instance), and its solutions.